# using stuff for fullname when task is same for two person even though fullname is not separating with comma

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT DISTINCT  

STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + U1.FullName
     from TM_user U1
     where u.TM_UserID=U1.TM_UserID

        FOR XML PATH ('')
   ), 1, 2, '') FullName,

task_name
FROM project  JOIN task 
               ON project.project_id=task.project_id
          JOIN timesheet  
               ON timesheet.task_id=task.task_id
          JOIN Team 
               ON project.project_id = Team.project_id
          JOIN TM_user u 
               ON u.TM_userID=timesheet.user_id

WHERE u.Is_Active=1 
and
u.report_to=13 
AND 
worked_dte BETWEEN '2014-03-18' AND '2014-03-21'
```

output i am getting

```
FullName                         task_name
Chandu Devathi                       new task 2222
Chandu Devathi                       TESST ePROM copy
Chandu Devathi                       Testing plz ignore.
Harish Kumar Ramakrishnappa      TESST ePROM copy
```

excepted output

```
FullName                                                   task_name
Chandu Devathi                                                 new task 2222
Chandu Devathi,Harish Kumar Ramakrishnapp                     TESST ePROM copy
Chandu Devathi                                                Testing plz ignore.
```

Comment: please see difference in both the outputs i want excepted output how to do that plz help me.

Comment: here i am using more table should i give all table structure?

Answer (score 0):

You should

1. add `GROUP BY task_name` into outer SELECT to get it working.
2. In inner SELECT use `WHERE` to filter records only for **task_name** from outer select.

Some time ago, I learned it from [this example](http://facility9.com/2010/06/push-ups-and-string-concatenation/).